# Search all categories

Tags: magento-1.9, database, catalogsearch, category-products

Some of the products weren't showing up in the search results on a site that I've been working on.

After looking at it for a while and logging the sql queries I've found that it's only searching the default category (category_id = 2).
The first query is:

```
SELECT `s`.`product_id`, 0 AS `relevance` 
FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
ON e.entity_id = s.product_id 
WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND ((`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%denim%'))
```

which has 26 results, the next query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` 
ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id 
  AND price_index.website_id = '1' 
  AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id 
  AND cat_index.store_id='1' 
  AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) 
  AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(<the previous product_ids>))
```

since the products aren't in the default category they aren't showing up. My question is how to change this so it searches all queries.

Answer (score 0):

First to check your all products number use this:

```
echo $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSize();
```

Then use this collection to get the collection of your all products:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // to get all attributes
                            ->setPageSize(5000) // to limit the results returned
                            ->setCurPage(1); // useful for pagination

        foreach ($collection as $product) {
          echo $product->getName().'<br />'; // some name
          echo $product->getId().'<br />'; // 1205 
          echo $product->getStatus().'<br />'; // 1 
          echo $product->getTypeId().'<br />'; // simple 
    }
```

To get all categories without filters

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
              echo $cat->getName().'<br />'; // some name
        }
```